# NuGet packages missing source mapping

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Trying to install a package from Nuget in Visual studio. When I found the package and clicked on it  I recieve this message: "Requires a package  source mapping" I have (of cource) searched and got several answers, but those don´t solve the problem. This suddenly happend, I have installed packages before. And it is  not for one projekt, the same occurs in every projekt!

To be able to install the package

Comment: My question was not folloing the rules. I make better next time!